# Like clause in MySQL is not showing the output as expected

Tags: mysql, enums

I created a procedure where in I had the value of column with enum datatype as 
  **Completeness_Type` ENUM('B', 'I', 'C', 'BC', 'BI', 'IC', 'BIC')**

I wrote a procedure where I would like to display all the video game records which does not have 'I' in completeness_type column. 
Below is the proceudre I have written

```
        USE `videogame_collection_3`;
        DROP procedure IF EXISTS `Get_Info_By_Games_missing_Something`;

          DELIMITER $$
         USE `videogame_collection_3`$$
                  create PROCEDURE `Get_Info_By_Games_missing_Something`(IN  Completenessip     VARCHAR(15))
   BEGIN
    SELECT 
      video_game.Game_Name,
      video_game.Genre,
      mycollection.Purchase_Date,
      mycollection.Purchase_Price,
       mycollection.`Condition`,
      platform.Platform_Name,
       mycollection.Completeness_Type
       FROM
      video_game
          INNER JOIN
         video_game_platform_mycollection ON video_game.Game_Id =    video_game_platform_mycollection.Game_Id
         INNER JOIN
           platform ON video_game_platform_mycollection.Platform_Id =      platform.Platform_Id
           INNER JOIN
       mycollection ON video_game_platform_mycollection.MyCollection_Id =      mycollection.MyCollection_Id
         where  mycollection.Completeness_Type not like '%Completenessip%';
      END
     $$

   DELIMITER ;
```

I am calling procedure with

**call Get_Info_By_Games_missing_Something('I');**

Expected output: I wouuld like to display completeness_type column which does not contain 'I'
So, the records in completenss_type column has to be 'B', 'C', 'BC'

So, could you please tell what is the mistake I am making?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you have a bad schema if you need to do a `LIKE` comparison on an enum. Perhaps you should consider breaking this up into multiple columns or use a bit field with bitwise operators if the letters in the enum each represent some sort of different property on the record.

Comment: If you take a step back and explain your intent of this field, you might get some better solutions to storing the data that would actually allow you to use an index for this portion of the WHERE clause, which you currently are not able to do with a `LIKE ('%...%')` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put the var Completenessip like that inside the LIKE string, you have to use CONCAT:

`not like CONCAT('%', Completenessip, '%');`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. But, it is not working for  the calls like call Get_Info_By_Games_missing_Something('BI') or call Get_Info_By_Games_missing_Something('BIC'); Could you please tell what to do for that? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It's the same... Maybe (I'm guessing) when you put "BI" you want the condition to considere "B" and "I" separatly, but the LIKE doesn't work like that, it consideres the whole string (BI).